# Show/Hide a field in an admin form based on value of another field

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, forms, system.xml

My module has 2 tabs. In one, there is a text field for an `API Key`. In the other, a `select` field gets populated based off an HTTP request that is made with the API Key. I have all this working fine. However, if the user has not entered an API key, I'd like to display a message to them about the need to do so, rather than showing the empty `Options` field.

## Screen 1 - API Key

[image]

## Screen 2 - Options

[image]

I'm hoping there is a way to do this purely through `system.xml`. I'd also be ok with just injecting some custom JavaScript onto the page, but I'd need instructions on how to do that as well.

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible in UI component with the `<switcherConfig>`. You can refer magento sales rule module form UI component file. I had a same requirement and I did it by using following code.

```
<field name="allow_to_proceed" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
        <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <dataType>boolean</dataType>
    <label translate="true">Allow Proceed to Checkout</label>
    <dataScope>allow_to_proceed</dataScope>
    <switcherConfig>
        <rules>
            <rule name="0">
                <value>1</value>
                <actions>
                    <action name="0">
                        <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.skip_other_rules</target>
                        <callback>show</callback>
                    </action>
                    <action name="1">
                        <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.remove_discount</target>
                        <callback>show</callback>
                    </action>
                </actions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="1">
                <value>0</value>
                <actions>
                    <action name="0">
                        <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.skip_other_rules</target>
                        <callback>hide</callback>
                    </action>
                    <action name="1">
                        <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.remove_discount</target>
                        <callback>hide</callback>
                    </action>
                </actions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </switcherConfig>        
</settings>
<formElements>
    <checkbox>
        <settings>
            <valueMap>
                <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
            </valueMap>
            <prefer>toggle</prefer>
        </settings>
    </checkbox>
</formElements>
```

Here `<target>` is your `form_datacomponent_name.section_name.field_name` .

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything extra default ui component give this functionality. you can use this code & change `field`, form namespace `vendor_module_form`, fieldset `general`. That's all!!

```
<field name="is_enable">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Enable</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">from_general</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_enable</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                    Here your message/comment go.
                </item>
                <item name="switcherConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="rules" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_form.vendor_module_form.general.field</item>
                                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_form.vendor_module_form.general.field</item>
                                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the depends tag in the system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="Sathya" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Sathya</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="ProductSliderSection" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Product Slider</label>
            <tab>Sathya</tab>
            <resource>Sathya_ProductSlider::ProductSlider</resource>
            <group id="productSlider" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="moduleEnable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="numberOfProducts" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Number of Product in the Slider</label>
                    <comment>No decimal points</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="moduleEnable">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

[image]

```
<field name="extension_attributes.use_custom_minimum_order_amount" formElement="checkbox" sortOrder="75">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataScope>extension_attributes.use_custom_minimum_order_amount</dataScope>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Use custom minimum order amount</label>
                <switcherConfig>
                    <rules>
                        <rule name="0">
                            <value>0</value>
                            <actions>
                                <action name="0">
                                    <target>custom_module_form.custom_module_form.general.extension_attributes.minimum_order_amount</target>
                                    <callback>hide</callback>
                                </action>
                            </actions>
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="1">
                            <value>1</value>
                            <actions>
                                <action name="0">
                                    <target>custom_module_form.custom_module_form.general.extension_attributes.minimum_order_amount</target>
                                    <callback>show</callback>
                                </action>
                            </actions>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </switcherConfig>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="extension_attributes.minimum_order_amount" formElement="input" sortOrder="80">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataScope>extension_attributes.minimum_order_amount</dataScope>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Minimum order amount</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
```